# PHP Headers to be sent "twice"

Tags: php

I have a page which includes my navbar.php in this file there is a section to log out a user and on success take the user to the login page :

```
<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

// ** Logout the current user. **
$logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
  $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
  //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
  $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
  unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
  unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
  unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);

  $logoutGoTo = "index.php?page=login";
  if ($logoutGoTo) {
    header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
    die();

  }
}
?>
```

On the page where the navbar is included I have php which uploads a file and writes to a database, but on success it also needs to go to a url, It outputs a warning "Headers already sent", I need this to work as the page seems to be "useless" when this is displayed (i.e Tab buttons become links and do not open the tab)
This is a small section of PHP for file upload:

```
// Upload success URL. User will be redirected to this page after upload.
define('SUCCESS_URL','index.php?page=update_about');

  header('Location: ' . SUCCESS_URL);
    die();

  break;

  } // while(true)

  // Errors. Show upload form.
  $message = join('',$errors);
  showUploadForm($message);

}
```

Comment: just don't output anything before `header()` and `session_start();`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send headers after content, it's impossible. There are two options (afaik). The **first and proper way** is to rethink your code and how it works. If you need to send a header after content you're doing something wrong.

The second way is to cheat and use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php). From [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php):

> This function will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead the output is stored in an internal buffer.

And then [`ob_end_flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php):

> This function will send the contents of the topmost output buffer (if any) and turn this output buffer off. If you want to further process the buffer's contents you have to call ob_get_contents() before ob_end_flush() as the buffer contents are discarded after ob_end_flush() is called.

Comment: You can actually leave out any `ob_end_*` call, it should be done automatically when the script ends afaik. I know it's even dirtier, but it's also a lot simpler/quicker. (Anyone having this problem should really go with your first way though.)

Comment: is there anything else to use besides (header) to redirect the user after log out??

Comment: No, the only way to redirect with PHP is using the header.

Comment: I have never use output buffering, could you possibly show me an example of how to use output buffering with the header redirect?

Comment: Or how about you rethink how your program flows so you log the person out before any output?